# How to invoke a bash script from xml file

Tags: xml, bash, command-line-interface

I am creating a CLI using **XML** commands with **klish** as **XML** parser

I want to invoke a bash file from the **XML** specifically from the **ACTION** tag just as given below,

```
<ACTION> "bash_file_invoke_from_here" </ACTION>
```

I am aware that it can be done, but I don't know the exact syntax {because I am new to the XML concepts}. I could't find it from any website. Please share the websites too if available.

Comment: Is the content of the `ACTION` tag just a shell script? Does just `path/to/file/to/run.sh` work?

Comment: I will check that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Yes it worked. @ Etan Reisner. Can u update it as your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the examples it appears that the `ACTION` tag just contains literal shell scripts.

As such it looks like you should just be able to put your script there to run it.

```
<ACTION>/path/to/your/script.sh</ACTION>
```

You'll need to make sure your script is executable of course.